# Add transition effect when an element become visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've some input fields hidden in my html like this:

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" />
<button class="hidden">click me!</button>
```

throught jquery I display such controls in this way:

```
$('input').removeClass('hidden');
```

This working pretty well, but I want add a fade effect when the element become visible. Is possible do this via css? So automatically when the element is visible a fade effect appear?

Comment: why not $('input').fadeIn()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#show').click(function(){
  $('.hidden').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="hidden" />
<button class="hidden">click me!</button>

<button id='show'>CLICK TO SHOW</button>
```